# I m using SSRS Report..I have a text box on SSRS report with too long sentence Can I add a break line in the sentence?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a text box on report with too long sentence
Can I add a break line in the sentence?How it can Possible in SSRS Report.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WIth requirements clarified:**

```
=LEFT("Leo's OfficeName",INSTR("Leo's OfficeName"," ") - 1) & VBCRLF & MID("Leo's OfficeName",INSTR("Leo's OfficeName"," ") + 1,LEN("Leo's OfficeName"))
```

ANd replace the text string with your column name.
The first part finds the first space and takes text from the start until that character, the second parts takes the remainder. If you have multiple spaces you will need to refine this further.

---

Assuming that the break isn't at the start of the sentence, break it up using `VBCRLF` - i.e.

```
="Text on first line goes here" & VBCRLF & "text on second line here"
```

**Edit** - using database variables:

```
=Fields!Variable.Value & VBCRLF & Fields!Vairable2.Value
```

And of course you can use a mix of database fields and static text if required:

```
= Fields!Variable.Value & VBCRLF & "Text on Second Line"
```

Comment: you can use the Expression option to split the text into however many characters u want per line, then use this method

Comment: i have value like this =Fields!OfficeName.Value and the OfficeName value is too big so,I want to split it and put it next line so,how it can be done?

Comment: @User993634 - please give some sample text and if there are any common rules which define where the split needs to go

Comment: for example OfficeName=Leo's BurnettOffice and i want that after 6 character the text shold be split.....